# elasticsearch query_string handle special characters

Tags: elasticsearch

My database is sync with an Elasticsearch to optimize our search results and request faster.

I have an issue querying the users, I want with a query therm look for my users, it can be part of a name, phone, ip, ...

My actual query is

```
query_string: { fields: ['id', 'email', 'firstName', 'lastName', 'phone', 'ip'], query: `*${escapeElastic(req.query.search.toString().toLowerCase())}*`}
```

Where `req.query.search` is my search and escapeElastic comes from the node module `elasticsearch-sanitize` because I had issues with some symbols.

I have some issue for example if I query for an ipv6, I will have `query: '*2001\\:0db8*'` but it will not find anything in the database and it should

Other issue if I have someone with firstName john-doe my query will be `query: '*john\\-doe*'` and it will not find any result.

Seems that the escape prevent query errors but create some issues in my case.

I do not know if `query_string` is the better way to do my request, I am open to suggestions to optimize this query

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect the analyzer on your fields is [`standard`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-analyzers.html) or similar. This means chars like `:` and `-` were stripped:

```
GET _analyze
{
  "text": "John-Doe",
  "analyzer": "standard"
}
```

showing

```
{
  "tokens" : [
    {
      "token" : "john",
      "start_offset" : 0,
      "end_offset" : 4,
      "type" : "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position" : 0
    },
    {
      "token" : "doe",
      "start_offset" : 5,
      "end_offset" : 8,
      "type" : "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position" : 1
    }
  ]
}
```

---

Let's create our own analyzer which is going to keep the special chars but lowercase them all other chars the same time:

```
PUT multisearch
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "with_special_chars": {
          "tokenizer": "whitespace",
          "filter": [
            "lowercase"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "firstName": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "with_special_chars": {
            "type": "text",
            "analyzer": "with_special_chars"
          }
        }
      },
      "ip": {
        "type": "ip",
        "fields": {
          "with_special_chars": {
            "type": "text",
            "analyzer": "with_special_chars"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Ingesting 2 sample docs:

```
POST multisearch/_doc
{
  "ip": "2001:0db8:85a3:0000:0000:8a2e:0370:7334"
}

POST multisearch/_doc
{
   "firstName": "John-Doe"
}
```

and applying your query from above:

```
GET multisearch/_search
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "fields": [
        "id",
        "email",
        "firstName.with_special_chars",
        "lastName",
        "phone",
        "ip.with_special_chars"
      ],
      "query": "2001\\:0db8* OR john-*"
    }
  }
}
```

both hits are returned.

---

Two remarks: 1) note that we were searching `.with_special_chars` instead of the main fields and 2) I've removed the leading wildcard from the ip -- those are highly inefficient.

---

Final tips since you asked for optimization suggestions: the query could be rewritten as

```
GET multisearch/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "term": {
            "id": "tegO63EBG_KW3EFnvQF8"
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "email": "john@doe.com"
          }
        },
        {
          "match_phrase_prefix": {
            "firstName.with_special_chars": "john-d"
          }
        },
        {
          "match_phrase_prefix": {
            "firstName.with_special_chars": "john-d"
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "phone.with_special_chars": "+151351"
          }
        },
        {
          "wildcard": {
            "ip.with_special_chars": {
              "value": "2001\\:0db8*"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

1. Partial `id` matching is probably an overkill -- either the `term` catches it or not
2. `email` can be simply `match`ed
3. `first-` & `lastName`: I suspect `match_phrase_prefix` is more performant than `wildcard` or `regexp` so I'd go with that (as long as you don't need the leading `*`)
4. `phone` can be `match`ed but do make sure special chars can be matched too (if you use the int'l format)
5. use `wildcard` for the `ip` -- same syntax as in the query string

Try the above and see if you notice any speed improvements!

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explication. Only one issue with the optimization, in my code I am receiving only one variable to search over all the fields, I can not apply your optimization has I need a different variable for all fields. In my case I do not know if the request is an ip, a phone number or an email

Comment: You're welcome. I suppose that's fine -- you don't need to know. That's why I used a `should` condition -- so at least 1 *should* match... Which ever it is, is for ES to decide.