# Search for "}" curly braces in field value in elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch

In elastic search we have a documents where field  example - "xyz" : "{123}"

How can we search for all documents where xyz field value have "{" in it.

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/61641672/8160318

Comment: You'll need to pick a predefined analyzer that doesn't remove curly braces or create a custom analyzer for `xyz` field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by @Evaldas, You need to use the custom analyzer which doesn't remove the `{}`, AS you have not provided your index mapping, sample documents, use below sample example to showcase how it can be achieved.

Index mapping with custom analyzer which uses [edge n-gram tokenizer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-edgengram-tokenizer.html)

```
{
    "settings": {
        "analysis": {
            "analyzer": {
                "autocomplete": {
                    "type": "custom",
                    "tokenizer": "edge_ngram",
                    "min_gram": 1,
                    "max_gram": 10,
                    "filter": [
                        "lowercase"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "mappings": {
        "properties": {
            "title": {
                "type": "text",
                "analyzer": "autocomplete"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Index sample docs**

```
{
    "title" : "123"
}

{
    "title" : "{123}"
}
```

**Search query**

```
{
    "query": {
        "match": {
            "title": {
                "query": "{"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**And search result**

```
 "hits": [
            {
                "_index": "65617970",
                "_type": "_doc",
                "_id": "1",
                "_score": 0.6931471,
                "_source": {
                    "title": "{123}"
                }
            }
        ]
```